# Numpy tests cannot parse version

Tags: python, git, numpy, python-versioneer

After forking the Numpy repository and setting up the dev container for it, I attempted to run `python runtests.py -v` but it returns the following error

```
Building, see build.log...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/numpy/setup.py", line 47, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(f'Cannot parse version {FULLVERSION}')
RuntimeError: Cannot parse version 0+untagged.32327.g0200e4a
```

I think it has something to do with the last commit being untagged, as `0200e4a` matches the first part of the last commit id, but tagging the commit and checking it out did not work.

Comment: can you show the command you used to tag your commit ? reading the code in setup.py, versioneer.py and setup.cfg, `numpy` expects version tags in the `vX.Y.Z` format (with a leading `v`)

Comment: This should be a question for [the numpy project](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues), if you're trying to work on their codebase and following their instructions doesn't lead to a working setup.

Comment: also, the [README](https://github.com/numpy/numpy#readme) indicates to run `python -c "import numpy, sys; sys.exit(numpy.test() is False)"`  (it wouldn't cost must to add a script, shell or python, and say "run that script", I'm just quoting the doc here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the code on the [numpy repository](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) (in `setup.py`, `versioneer.py` and `setup.cfg`):

numpy expects version tags in the `vX.Y.Z[suffix]` format (with a leading `v`, and 3 dot separated numbers)

```
git tag v1.2.3.dev
```

---

Also worth noting: the Readme gives instructions to run the tests with:

```
python -c "import numpy, sys; sys.exit(numpy.test() is False)"
```

so if you don't need to also test the build step, you may try that.

I'm not competent enough to say if this instruction is still up to date, though.

Comment: Heads up to anyone working on Numpy specifically that they should run `git pull upstream main --tags` in order to try get theirs working instead of the tagging method.

Comment: @agctute : this should probably be reported directly to the numpy project. open an issue there.

Answer (score 1):

I can get past this error by running `versioneer install --vendor`, as per https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer#vendored-mode. But I'm not sure if and how this will conflict with upstream NumPy changes, which you will want to sync in the fork. Unfortunately, I can't find anything about this in the NumPy GitHub wiki at first glance.